# Append value to a list from specific type

Tags: python

I have a `Agent` class as below:

```
import Point
import random

class Agent(object):
    """description of class"""

    locationX = 0
    locationY = 0

    def __init__(self, point = None):
        self.locationX = point.x
        self.locationY = point.y

    def GenerateAgents(numberOfAgents):
        agentList = []
        while len(agentList) < numberOfAgents:

            point = Point.Point()
            point.x = random.randint(0, 99)
            point.y = random.randint(0, 99)

            agent = Agent(point)
            agentList.append(agent)
        return agentList

    def AppendValue(agentList):
        for item in agentList:
            item.append(False)
        return agentList

    def GetAgentCoordinate(agentList, agentIndex):
        for agent in agentList:
            return agentList[agentIndex]
```

in addition to a `Point` class just like this:

```
import math

class Point(object):
    """description of class"""

    x = 0
    y = 0

    def __init__(self, x = None, y = None):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def GetDistance(point1, point2):
        return math.sqrt(math.pow(point1.x - point2.x, 2) +
                         math.pow(point1.y - point2.y))
```

Here is the `Main` class:

```
import Agent
import Point

if __name__ == "__main__":

    agentList = Agent.Agent.GenerateAgents(100)
    selectedAgent = Agent.Agent.GetAgentCoordinate(agentList, 10)
    myList = Agent.Agent.AppendValue(agentList)    //ERROR!
```

I am going to append `False` value to each sub-list of `agentList`. But here is the traceback. The `Appendvalue` has been defined in my `Agent` class and `append` has been taken into account for a `list` but I don't figure the problem out.

It might sounds a stupid mistake... Would you please clearing the case?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio  12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.1\visualstudio_py_util.py", line 106, in
exec_file
exec_code(code, file, global_variables)
File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.1\visualstudio_py_util.py", line 82, in exec_code
exec(code_obj, global_variables)  File "C:\Users\Matinking\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\NeuroSimulation\NeuroSimulation\Main.py", line 8, in <module>
myList = Agent.Agent.AppendValue(agentList)  File    "C:\Users\Matinking\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\NeuroSimulation
\NeuroSimulation\Agent.py", line 28, in AppendValue
item.append(False)
AttributeError: 'Agent' object has no attribute 'append'
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: First of all, you should provide a _minimal_ example demonstrating the problem. Second, I think the error message is pretty clear, what exactly is your problem?

Comment: `agentList` is not a list of lists. It is a list of `Agent` objects (`agentList.append(agent)`).

Comment: You are using classes totally wrong. 1) don't define the variabes `locationX` and `locationY` outside of a function -- you are actually creating class methods here and that is not what you want. 2) make the first argument of *every* class method `self`. If you want static methods, use the `@staticmethd` decorator, or even better just use plain functions instead!

Answer (score 1):

I think the mistake is here:

```
def AppendValue(agentList):
    for item in agentList:
        item.append(False) #Precisely here
    return agentList
```

You are trying to perform a method that is for list  whereas `item` is an element (not a list) from `agentList`(which is a list of Agent Objects)

Also, I see that you can optimize the following code:

```
def GetAgentCoordinate(agentList, agentIndex):
        for agent in agentList:
            return agentList[agentIndex]
```

To just:

```
def GetAgentCoordinate(agentList, agentIndex):
    return agentList[agentIndex]
```

Comment: Thank you for the declaration and the hints... Actually each `item` itself should be a list. As a matter of fact I have tried to define `agentList` in a manner to be a list of lists... How can I handle this case, practically?

Comment: The Concept of List of Lists is easy, you just think of elements of main list as list, just like you think of element of List of integers as integers, example:
L1 = [1,2,3]
L2 = ['a','b','c']
L3 = [True, False, True]
L = []
L.append(L1)
L.append(L2)
L.append(L3)
# L will be [[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c'], [True, False, True]]

Comment: I did tried with `agentList.append([agent])` but after appending `False`, all of the elements, i.e. `locationX`, `locationY` and `False` are not within the same list level. I mean the result will be [[lx, ly], False], instead of [lx, ly, False]....

Comment: Can u post again your code with the modification you did?

Comment: The case has been resolved by using `extend` method, instead of `append` method... Thanks